# How can I make the image change based on the domain name visited? Using location.hostname

Tags: javascript, html, css, hostname

I have one website and two domain names. I want image "A" to appear if the visitor goes to 
a page on www.SampleSiteA.com but image "B" should appear if on a page from www.SampleSiteB.com.

Unfortunately the result of my code below is blank, with no image appearing at all.  Any ideas?

content for file: welcome.html

```
<html>
<head>
     <script src="resources/js/domain.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
     <div class="welcomepic"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Content for file: styles.css

```
.picForA{
    background-image: url('../img/A.png');
}
.picForB{
    background-image: url('../img/B.png');
}
.welcomepic{
    background-position:left center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding-left:160px;
    width:225px;
    float:left;
    height:100px;
    display: block;
}
```

Content of file: domain.js

```
function welcomepic() {
    if (location.hostname == 'www.SampleSiteA.com') {
        $('.welcomepic').addClass('picForA');
    } else {
        $('.welcomepic').addClass('picForB');
    }
}
```

Comment: And when do you call `welcomepic`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you do not call your function. A solution would be to ad the following code to the head of the html.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
welcomepic();
});
```

you also need to remove the previous set class in the welcompic function otherwise you'll end up with double classes.

```
function welcomepic() {
    if (location.hostname == 'www.SampleSiteA.com') {
        $('.welcomepic').removeClass('picForB').addClass('picForA');
    } else {
        $('.welcomepic').removeClass('picForA').addClass('picForB');
    }
}
```

Comment: Image display is not consistent.  In lieu of location.hostname, would it be more efficient to use document.domain?  Perhaps without the www?

Comment: Based on initial tests, the code performs as expected without having the removeClass.  Is there a hidden danger if I continue to use the code without removeClass?

Comment: hi, no it is not necessary because you stay on the same domain after $(document).ready. however if you had to switch classes on click event, you'll had to do removeClass or toggleClass. Didn't thought  about it when I wrote my answer.